# How to setup the watch for multidimensional array of records element value?

Tags: debugging, freepascal, lazarus

Using the following code when I add watch for the value of:

```
A[1, 1].IsX
```

and put the breakpoint on the commented line below, the watch list shows this message:

```
Type array [1..3] of TBLOCK is not a structure or union type.
```

instead of showing the record element value. Here is the sample code:

```
type
  TBlock = record
    IsX: Boolean;
    IsO: Boolean;
    IsEmpty: Boolean;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  A: array[1..9, 1..3] of TBlock;
begin
  A[1, 1].IsX := True;
  // add watch for A[1, 1].IsX and set the breakpoint on the following line
  if A[1, 1].IsX then
    ShowMessage('Prevent against debugger elimination.');
end;
```

A screenshot from the watchlist:

[image]

How to properly setup the watch for the multidimensional array of records element value ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the watch like this instead:

```
A[1][1].IsX
```

I can't tell you why the original way displays that error message, but the way above works for me:

[image]